# Select ID from GROUP BY group if the group satisfied criteria

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I am working on an Access database which keeps records of all the different batches arrived to and shipped from the warehouse. The locations in Warehouse are indicated by Lot_ID.
The table contains the following data:

```
Batch_ID | Lot_ID |Arrival_date | Shipping_date
------------------------------------------------------
1        |  1     | 2013/7/08   | 2013/8/21 
2        |  2     | 2013/7/10   |   
3        |  3     | 2013/7/15   | 2013/8/28 
4        |  1     | 2013/7/22   | 2013/8/23 
5        |  3     | 2013/8/12   |
```

I am trying to write a query which would show only Lot_IDs which are currently not occupied.

The problem arises because the table contain both current and historical data. My idea is to group the table by Lot_ID and choose only those groups where Shipping_date of every row in the group is not null (which means every Batch which was stored in the Lot was shipped already and currently the Lot is free)

So the result would be:

```
Batch_ID  
--------- 
1
```

So what sql query would be better to use in this case?

Comment: in the result, did you mean Lot_ID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT Lot_ID
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY Lot_ID
HAVING SUM(IIF(Shipping_date IS NULL, 1, 0)) = 0
```

Output:

```
|Lot_ID |
|-------|
|     1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check beluw link 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

should use where caluse like 'where shipping_date = null  '

Answer (score 0):

Select all lot ids where the shipping date is not null and the lot id doesn't have a null shipping date.

The inner query will give you all lots that are yet to ship which means they are not free.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOT_ID
FROM tableName
WHERE Shipping_date IS NOT NULL 
      AND LOT_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT LOT_ID
                          FROM tableName
                          WHERE Shipping_date IS NULL)
```

Even selecting all lot ids which do not have a null shipping date should also work

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOT_ID
FROM tableName
WHERE  LOT_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT LOT_ID
                          FROM tableName
                          WHERE Shipping_date IS NULL)
```